# asp.net 2.0 calendar control

Tags: asp.net, calendar

I'm using the simple calendar control in ASP.NET 2.0. It has a simple format, and what I want to do, is select 10 years before the active date.

When I click on the link, I can scroll through the months, but not the years.

How can I scroll in the years, such that navigation becomes easy if the user has to select 10 years before the given date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default calendar control is very limited and I don't think you can do what you are trying to do with it. But there are plenty for javascript based calendar controls out that that you could use. There is also the [asp.net Ajax Calendar](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/calendar/calendar.aspx) control that I have used that has year navigation. If you click on the header (April, 2011), it will let you navigate by Months and if you click the header again then you can navigate by year.
[image]

Comment: i know but when i used javascript .. or ajax.. i cant make it runat=server in tht text box and there r many post backs.. in my page.. iam not able to retrieve in code behind...I too referred same link..

Comment: the asp.net ajax library provides extensions to existing controls so you can keep your server side textbox intact.

Comment: iam using 2010 with aso.net 2.0 i downloaded tool kit from msdn... but there were a lott of errors.. can u just show how u accessed in code behind